# 14.04.01 32-bit: Missing g++ 64-bit include files when cross-compiling

Tags: 64-bit, gcc, c++, g++, cross-compilation

So, I've got 32-bit Xubuntu 14.04.1 installed. We have some interface code where we intend to release SOs for the various platforms we support, and Windows DLLs.  (Yes I know, binary release bad, but also not relevant here.)

I'm trying to build 32-bit and 64-bit SOs with 32-bit 14.04.01, using `-m32`/`-m64` gcc/g++ arguments.  The 32-bit version works fine, but the 64-bit version fails with

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/string:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
```

Checking in the includes, that file is genuinely present for 32-bit but missing for 64-bit.

Googling the problem, this seems to have happened in the past for GCC/G++ 4.6, but then is marked as fixed.  But 14.04.1 is using GCC/G++ 4.8, which suggests there's been a regression in those libraries in GCC/G++ 4.8.  Is this something that anyone else has seen?

I could set up a new VM for 64-bit 14.04.1 if necessary and see whether that would pick up the right library versions. I'd rather not if possible though, because I've got a bunch of other stuff I'd have to reinstall as well.  Is there a better solution?  And if I did install 64-bit 14.04.1, would I definitely be able to cross-compile back to 32-bit without missing headers in the other direction?

Comment: ...perhaps you should avoid mentioning stuff that is "not relevant here", since it is not relevant.

Comment: Did you install the `g++-multilib` package?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks - that was it!  Looks like the 64-bit install has it by default, but the 32-bit install doesn't.  OK, something else to add to my "how to set up a Linux build VM" checklist. :)  It may seem basic, but I didn't spot this as an answer in other people's questions for the same compile error, and I'm not really a Linux expert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 64-bit bits/c++config.h file is provided on 32-bit systems (and vice-versa) by installing the `g++-multilib` package, so you need to install that package either using Software Center, Synaptic, or via the terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

This is just a dependency package that resolves to `g++-4.8-multilib` for the default gcc/g++ version, and in turn depends on `lib64stdc++-4.8-dev` (64-bit compilation on 32-bit) or `libx32stdc++-4.8-dev` (32-bit compilation on 64-bit) - it is these that contain the actual header files.

There is an equivalent set of packages for the plain C compiler `gcc`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install g++-5-multilib` got me the version I needed.  If this does not work for you, note `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && sudo apt-get update` is also part of my config.